# VSTO Outlook: How to show outlook-addin custom task pane expanded by default with a defined height

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have created and Outlook Add-in and I have created below Outlook custom task pane:

```
this.myUserControl = new myUserControl();
this.myCustomTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(this.myUserControl, Properties.Resources.myText, this.Window);
this.myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionTop;
this.myCustomTaskPane.DockPositionRestrict = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
this.myCustomTaskPane.Height = 80;
this.myCustomTaskPane.Visible = false;
```

As you can see by default is not visible. Later under some conditions I make it visible:

```
this.myCustomTaskPane .Visible = true;
```

but the task pane is being shown collapsed. How can I make it expanded by default with the height I set?

I need to manually choose "resize" option from the custom task pane menu and I do not want this. I want it to be expanded with the custom height (80) by default. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom task panes don't provide the collapsed/expanded states unlike Outlook form regions.

The minimum height depends on several factors, and can change in future releases of Microsoft Office. If you try to set the `Height` property to a value that is less than the minimum height, the application will automatically reassign the `Height` property to the minimum height.

So, you just need to increase the size of the task pane to get it displayed expanded. Check out my post on the similar thread - [How to Minimize/Collapse outlook-addin custom task pane as same as Folder Pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966009/how-to-minimize-collapse-outlook-addin-custom-task-pane-as-same-as-folder-pane).

Read more about dealing with custom task panes in Outlook in the [Walkthrough: Display custom task panes with email messages in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) article.

Comment: Yes, increasing the size (height) of the task pane works. I was set to a height very little.